# JXA: Manipulating windows by their ID

Tags: macos, javascript-automation

Instead of

```
Application("Preview").windows[0].bounds = {"x": 1440, "y":25, "width":1440, "height": 2535}
```

I'd like to move the window but instead of using an index, I'd like to use the window's ID. I got the ID with

```
Application("Preview").windows[0].id();
```

But when I replace the index with the ID:

```
Application("Preview").windows.whose({id: 15596}).bounds = {"x": 1440, "y":25, "width":1440, "height": 2535}
```

I get

> Error -1728: Can't get object.

Comment: Ok, I made some progress. I can use whose to select the window by id, but I still can't move it. Ex `Application("Preview").windows.whose({"id": {"=": 15596}}).bounds();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between the window `id` given by the `Application` object, the window `id` tracked by the `Application('System Events')` object, and the window `id` tracked by the `CoreGraphics` framework.

Unless the developer of the application wrote a scripting exposure for manipulating window bounds into their app, you can't use the `Application` object to adjust bounds, you have to use `Application('System Events')` or use the Objective-C bridge to access the `AXUIElement` sub-system directly.

For example, using `Application('System Events')`:

```js
const window = Application('System Events')
  .applicationProcesses
  .whose({name: 'Safari'}).at(0)
  .windows.at(0);

window.position.set([0, 0]);
window.size.set([1200, 1000]);

return 0;
```

Note that there isn't any addressing of the window by its `id`, because the System Events process isn't aware of such application-tracked IDs.

---

If you needed to narrow the scope of your window selection by its title or other characteristic, you can do so using JavaScript's `Array.prototype.find()` or `Array.prototype.filter()`:

```js
const SafariEvents = Application('System Events')
  .applicationProcesses
  .whose({name: 'Safari'})
  .at(0);

const window = SafariEvents.windows()
  .find((window) => !!window.attributes
                      .byName('AXTitle').value()
                      .match(/JXA/));

window.position.set([0, 0]);
window.size.set([1200, 1000]);

return 0;
```

Take care to notice the extremely-verbose syntax of extracting accessibility attributes from the System Events scripting object. While it's lengthy, it *does* give you the ability to use things like regular expressions to help find what you want — a *much* better alternative to native AppleScript's hodgepodge of search/find mechanisms.

---

Saving the best for last, you can use the Objective-C bridge to access the accessibility subsystem directly. This requires dealing with pointers and is a little more complex than the previous examples, but it is ***significantly*** faster than using System Events (I can't emphasize that enough — it's nuts how responsive this approach is).

I've made a gist with helper functions to make this easier. It includes an example of adjusting the position of a Visual Studio Code window. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/stephancasas/77592228a3f34a533301305d423f05e8) if you'd like to try it.

Cheers.